# Problem baking normal map

Tags: normals, baking

[image]hi ive just recently installed version 2.73a and i am trying to bake my normal maps. I am doing it the same as i have in previous versions but now i keep getting the same error, as circle on attached picture. Can anyone help me with this or direct me to a current tutorial on baking normals?

Answer (score 3):

According to your screenshot you're using cycles, the workflow is different.

In *Object Mode*

- Select your object <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Add an image texture node with the image selected.
- Press *Bake*

[image]

To bake from one object to another select two objects and tick the *Select to Active* option.

[image]

Comment: cheers for that, I changed it back to blender render and bam it worked lol I must have switched mode some how. Thanks again :)